# PHP SoapClient malformed xml

Tags: php, soap

I'm communicating with a webservice in SOAP with php. Here's my code :

```
$data = array('name' => 'test', 'age' => 20);
$WDSL = 'http://xxx.xxxxx.xxx/wdsl.ibs?wsdl';
$SOAP = new SoapClient($WDSL, array('trace' => true));
$RESULT = $SOAP->__soapCall('Some_Service', $data);
```

For some reason, the XML is wrong :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Some_Crap"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:Some_Service/><param1>test</param1><param2>20</param2> ...
```

How come the XML node name is paramX when it should be the variable name ? What am i doing wrong ??

Thanks

Update : 
So I've listed the functions from that webservice and what I get is :

```
Some_Service_Response Some_Service(Some_Service $parameters))
```

I changed my call so it is now :

```
$SOAP->__call('Some_Service', array('Some_Service', $data));
```

And the XML is still wrong :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="urn:iwaysoftware:ibse:jul2003:HR_Master"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:Some_Service/>
<param1><item><key>SomeKey</key><value>SomeValue</value> ....
```

I still get  `<param1><item><key>SomeKey</key><value>SomeValue</value> instead of
<Somekey>SomeValue</Somekey>`

So the question is, is the Web Service not working properly or is it on my end ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were you I'd try setting up $data in an object format.

```
$data = array('name' => 'test', 'age' => 20);
```

**For example:**

```
$data = null;
$data->name = "test";
$data->age = 20;

$RESULT = $SOAP->__soapCall('Some_Service', $data);
```

Comment: How does this work?  The docs (http://www.php.net/manual/pl/soapclient.soapcall.php) say the second parameter of `__soapCall` must be an array.

Comment: I know.. hence that post and that answer didn't really 'match' the doc... so I guess doc not up to date ?

Comment: For those having issues with this, you must use an array with soapCall, however if you call the function directly you can use an object type as suggested here.

Answer (score 9):

The `SoapClient` class makes many corrections based on the WSDL of the service, e.g. removes invalid tags. Check the WSDL, it may contain that the name of the parameters are `param1` and `param2`.

Calling `SoapClient::__getFunctions()` and `SoapClient::__getTypes()` and dumping the results gives a fairly good summary what PHP understood from your WSDL.

---

(After the OP updated the question that of the output of `SoapClient::__getFunctions()` is:

```
Some_Service_Response Some_Service(Some_Service $parameters))
```

)

Usually the array key is the parameter name, not the type. So my first guess would be:

```
$SOAP->__call('Some_Service', array('parameters', $data));
```

The problem may be on the server-side though. WSDL incompatibilities sometimes require hand-tuning of the WSDL files so that PHP emits the same XML that you want.

But before doing any hacking (if you have the chance) **be sure to try out the service without PHP** to see the reaction of the service to different XML files. A nice program called [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) can do this for you, it automatically generates XML stubs to test. (I only had problems with SoapUI with web services that needed digital signatures.)

Based on the results of the XML testing you may need to:

- Hand-tune the WSDL
- Generate the XML file by hand and send that to the web server (last resort)
- If the XML is almost correct, it just needs a small fine tuning you can also derive from the `SoapClient` class and override the `SoapClient::__doRequest` method to do string manipulations on the XML file before submitting to the server (by calling the `__dorequest` of the base class). One example, when I used this solution when the web service required some XML attributes to be resent on some tags.

Comment: Here's what I get :Array ( [0] => struct ibsinfo { string service; string method; string license; string disposition; string Username; string Password; string language; } [1] => struct adapterexception { string error; } [2] => struct Some_Service { Some_Service_ComplexType hr_master; } [3] => struct Some_Service_ComplexType { WS_Transaction_ID WS_Transaction_ID; Web_Service_Request_Type...

Comment: Please put it in the question because (a) it belong there (b) comments can't have newlines to improve readability (c) comments have limited length and the interesting part is missing

Comment: Csq, thanks for your explanation.  array('parameters', $data) does no good, in fact same thing as array('somecrap', $data). I'll give you the reward even if I can't solve that issue properly.