# Remove whitespaces from SoapClient request in PHP

Tags: php, soap, microsoft-dynamics, nav, navision

I'm creating a SOAP request via PHP native `SoapClient` class. When I dump the request using `SoapClient::__getLastRequest` I'll get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/itemb2cws"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:ReadMultiple><ns1:filter/><ns1:setSize>100</ns1:setSize></ns1:ReadMultiple></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Is there any way, how to remove the line feed or any other whitespace between XML elements?
Our client is using some old version of ERP Microsoft Dynamics Nav and the server falls when gets whitespace in request.

Comment: You should add the resolution as an answer, so that future visitors will understand :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Via [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363147/php-soapclient-malformed-xml#:~:text=override%20the%20SoapClient::__doRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363147/php-soapclient-malformed-xml#:%7E:text=override%20the%20SoapClient::__doRequest)

Just extend native PHP SoapClient and override the SoapClient::__doRequest() method.

Example:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);


namespace App\Soap;


use SoapClient;

class Client extends SoapClient
{
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
    {
        $request = $this->filter($request);

        parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
    }

    private function filter(string $request): string
    {
        return preg_replace( '#\R+#', '', $request);
    }
}
```

And you're done.